# Upside down tab like tabzilla from the Mozilla.com website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs

Mozilla.com has this tab on the top of their site that you can click and a menu drops down. I have a client who wants me to do the same thing but upside down, from the bottom half of the page. Apparently this is a really hard request. How do I make something like tabzilla that goes up and either overlaps or pushes the content away? Thanks!

Update: I love you guys.

Edit: http://hemakessites.com/mayukh/4/ Why does the top "Sign In/Register" pop down and the "Toggle" on the bottom pops up? I'm not seeing the difference besides 'top' and 'bottom' in the css. How does that change the direction of the popup?

Also, clicking the '337-9147' will expand the menu. I only want the button region to be clickable. How can I accomplish this?

You guys are awesome and I'm going to return the favor by answering some questions on here when I get time.

Comment: Overlaps or pushes the content away is two questions.  In general, you just need a footer and roughly the same JS.

Comment: If you are ok with it overlapping, use  position: fixed; bottom:0px; z-index: 999; on your menu. Then you'll need some jquery or javascript to animate the menu to open. I would elaborate but it sucks writing code from my phone...

Answer (score 1):

I took a similar approach as others, in that you set a div to have a fixed, or absolute position at the bottom of the screen (depending on whether the tab should always be visible, or only at the very bottom). Then, you can write some very simple javascript to vary the height of the element, and as the bottom is fixed, it will cause the tab to rise into the screen.

Essentially all you need is

```
.container{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -1px;    
}
```

And

```
$('.container').toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'205px'}, 500)
},function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'20px'}, 200)           
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QCmUp/).

Comment: css solution is not simple for you ? :)

Comment: Only a few new browsers support CSS3.

Comment: Only a few old browsers do not support :) Hey it is end of 2012, you can use modernize.js to fallback to js version of same. also what i really wanted to show is using margin to unhide fixed element, in jquery version it will be `animate({margin-top: '-300px'})`

Comment: http://hemakessites.com/mayukh/4/

Why does the toggle on the bottom go up and the "Register/Sign In" on the top go down? I'm not getting this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually what happens with elements is they are positioned according to their top/left point, so when you increase the height the top/left point stays fixed and the element 'moves' down. Because we fixed the 'bottom' attribute of the toggle to below the screen it gets precedence over the top/left default. Now when we modify its height, the bottom must stay fixed so it instead 'moves' up the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was lazy to make here click handler, so it is css3 only hover [sample](http://jsbin.com/olasah/5/)

I used fixed position with {top: 100%}, transition for animation, margin <0 to show;

HTML

```
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="handler">handler</div>
    <div id="menucontent">
    menu menu<br>
    menu menu<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   <div> text   text   text</div>
   <div> text   text   text</div>
   <!-- many of them -->
   <div> text   text   text</div>
   <div> text   text   text</div>
   <div> text   text   text</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#content > div {
 font-size: 2em; 
 height: 2.1em;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
#menu {
 left: 30px;
 position: fixed;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 top: 100%;
 border: 1px solid red;
 background: white;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s;
 -mozilla-transition: all 1s;
 -o-transition: all 1s;
 transition: all 1s;
}
#menu #handler {
 position: absolute;
 top: -40px;
 background: green;
 font-size: 30px;
 height: 40px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 left: 10px;
}
#menu:hover {
 margin-top: -300px; 

}
```

[with click](http://jsbin.com/olasah/7/), [or](http://jsbin.com/olasah/9/)

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu #handler').click(function() {
  $('#menu').toggleClass('shown');
  });
});
```

in css change `hover` to class `shown`

```
#menu.shown {
 margin-top: -300px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery solution, which is smoother than css3:

So, you'll want to do something like this jsfiddle (NOTE: This requires jQuery):
http://jsfiddle.net/cFkn2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab').click(function() {
        if ($('#tab').css('height') == '20px') {
            $('#tab').animate({
                height: '100px'
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            $('#tab').animate({
                height: '20px'
            }, 1000);
        };
    });
});
```

and

```
#tab{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    height:20px;
}
```

and

```
<div id="tab">CONTENT</div>
```

Style, edit, and add easing to taste.